# there exsit a real coefficient polynomial $g(x)$ of degree $n$. and for complex numbers $z(|z|=1)$ have $|g(z)|^2=1+|f(z)|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, contest-math

Let $n$ be give postive integers. such for any  real coefficient polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$,show that:there exsit a  real coefficient polynomial $g(x)$ of degree $n$.
and for complex numbers $z(|z|=1)$ have
$$|g(z)|^2=1+|f(z)|^2$$

maybe can use Rouche's theorem solve it?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

The expression 
$$
1+f(z)f(z^{-1})
$$
is symmetric under the map $z\mapsto z^{-1}$. Its roots come thus either in pairs $r,r^{-1}$ for real roots or as quadruples $ζ,\bar ζ,ζ^{-1},\bar ζ^{-1}$.
Assign half the roots to $g$, the complex ones in conjugate pairs, and compute the product of linear factors. Add a constant factor $c$ so that $g(1)^2=1+f(1)^2$. 
$$
g(z)=c\prod(z-r_i)\prod(z-ζ_k)(z-\bar ζ_k)
$$
is then one possible solution.